# What is the proper way to use Facebook Pixel code from multiple partners on one page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-pixel

We currently load the Facebook Pixel JS code in our React app's `<head>`. This includes the whole `<script>...</script>` section which mounts `fbq`/`_fbq` to the `window` and fires off our `PageView` events.

We have created a landing page on our site that a 3rd party partner will be directing traffic to. They would like us to include their FB Pixel tracking code on the page. For the life of us we haven't been able to find good *technical* documentation on this.

What we currently do:

```
...
componentDidMount() {
  let switched = false;
  const partnerId = this.props.params.partnerId;

  // This is an example. Basically, we have a generic version of
  // the page which looks like /partner/:partnerId, and we only want to
  // fire the FB Pixel tracking events for the right partner
  if (partnerId === 10) {
    window.fbq('init', '2999'); // Example partner ID
    window.fbq('track', 'PageView');
    window.fbq('track', 'Lead');
    switched = true;
  }

  // Switch back to using our Pixel so that we don't break our tracking
  if (switched) {
    window.fbq('init', '8888'); // Our example ID
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? We were trying to looking into using `fbq.push()`, and got as far as doing `fbq.push(['track', '2999'])` which will send a `PageView` event we think, but we couldn't figure out how to modify it to send a `Lead` event, and, there is no documentation that we could find for it.

The documentation that we know of:

- [FB Tag API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/tag-api)
- [FB Pixel Setup v2.8](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/facebook-pixel/v2.8)
- [FB Pixel Standard Events v2.8](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/facebook-pixel/v2.8#standardevents)
- [FB Pixel for Dynamic Ads](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/pixel-with-ads/dynamic-product-ads#getting-the-js-code-for-tracking)
- [FB KB: What are standard events and how do I use them?](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/402791146561655)

Comment: @CBroe I already linked to both of those docs in my question. Neither of them says how to send a `Lead` event using `fbq.push` to a specific ID. They simply show the structure of a `Lead` event

Comment: We're doing something similar, however we're findiing that the Lead events get fired multiple times even if it's in componentDidMount() - did you end up getting this working?

Comment: @DaleKing we dropped this feature from our product in early 2017. We haven't looked at it since then, but we did not figure out anything better than the above. Best of luck in your search, and please let us know if you figure something better out!